# Random number in Gift Code format?

Tags: php, random

I have this code which generates random strings in the following format:
    `XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX`
    `ex: GTSF-7H4KHT-7TGD`

`$n1 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,4);
    $n2 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,6);
    $n3 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,4);
    $code = $n1."-".$n2."-".$n3;
echo $code;`

I need to make the letters capital but have no idea how since i am a PHP newbie
Or is it better to just use CSS like `text-transform` to make it uppercase?

Comment: [For future reference, just use google for questions like this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+capitalize+letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`strtoupper()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) function:

```
$n1 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,4);
$n2 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,6);
$n3 = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),17,4);
$code = $n1."-".$n2."-".$n3;
echo strtoupper($code);
```

**[Example](http://codepad.org/6V43LydB)**

Or, if you prefer, as you also suggested you could use CSS:

```
p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: One caveat to text-transform, it changes the display but not the underlying text. A user who tries to copy the gift code from a web page will get the original format (with lowercase letters) in his clipboard.